# Write variables automatically into child class

Tags: java, android, oop

I’m trying to achieve the following. I have several a Model that has some basic Methods, such as saveModel, loadModel, laodModel from. Now, I have other classes that extend this Model, e.g. User and Movie.

User now has the variables

```
id
userName
userMail
userPW
```

Movie has

```
id
movieTitle
movieLength
movieGenre
```

Now, I create a new User object and load it from the database. So now I when I load a model from Movie, I have a JSON-Object containing the following information:

```
id = x
movieTitle = "bla"
movieLength = "bla"
movieGenre = "bla"
```

As you can see, the jSON contains the correct key and values, now I just have to write them into the child Model. How is it possible, that my Model now writes all the field values into the user object? In PHP I would do it simply like this

```
foreach ($row as $key=>$val) {
            $this->$key = $val;
}
```

In Java, however it doesn’t seem to be possible. So how can the parent class automatically write variables into the child class. Or isn’t this possible and I have to do it manually? The problem I see here, is, that I would have to do it for every Model again, when I could just do it in the super class. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to define your parent class to have maps holding all possible fields; and to have the child class define its fields as contained in enums. So from parent class level you simply serialize all the maps and their key-value pairs. Use generic with enum as parameter to give you flexibility on what key / key type to use.

Having said so, it's best you have a code generator which generates the child classes; if you wish, you can also generate the individual method for each field pointing to a specific key in the maps as well.

Comment: Yeah, this is how I did it now. I will edit now my question for others to see. Is there still a better way to do this?

Comment: @Musterknabe Frankly I think this method is good enough. There is no performance penalty at all in term of getters, setters and IO cost. There is little drawback to the readability of code if you add the per field methods calling the map with specific fields; and as long as you using enum, it's essentially an array in memory so not too much memory penalty either. So I think it's good enough.